# JS nesting problem, variable comes back unidentified any way

Tags: javascript

I tried to do a compound interest calculator for a prog lesson in JS, and ended up with a problem : **variables I initialized on a higher level are unidentified in a lower level**. I read the *opposite* was true, I read about nested function, function scope and all and tried to put the compoundI function in another one but nothing solved it until now. An idea ?

```
/* TODO
 * 10 000€ placed for 20 years at 4% per year
 */

;
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var cash;
    var tau;
    var yea;
    var an;

    cash = parseInt(prompt("T'as CB sur ta CB ?", "10000"));
    tau = parseInt(prompt("% d'intérêt annuel", "4"));
    yea = parseInt(prompt("Nombre d'années", "20"));
    an = 0;

    var compoundI = function (cash, tau, yea, an) {
        while (an < yea) {
            an++;
            cash = cash * (100 + tau) / 100;
            compoundI(cash, tau, yea, an);
            alert(cash);
            break;
        }
    //here, alert(yea) gives "unidentified, so the while loop can't happen. 
    //Why my declared variables aren't recognized in the compoundI function ?
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because you named the arguments of `compoundI` the same as your variables doesn't make it work magically, you still need to call `compoundI` initially. See the second to last line of my solution below

To put it more directly, you can name your function arguments anything, they don't have to be the same name as the variables which hold the values you pass into it.

#### Solution

```js
/* TODO
 * 10 000€ placed for 20 years at 4% per year
 */

;
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var cash;
    var tau;
    var yea;
    var an;

    cash = parseInt(prompt("T'as CB sur ta CB ?", "10000"));
    tau = parseInt(prompt("% d'intérêt annuel", "4"));
    yea = parseInt(prompt("Nombre d'années", "20"));
    an = 0;

    var compoundI = function (cash, tau, yea, an) {
        while (an < yea) {
            an++;
            cash = cash * (100 + tau) / 100;
            compoundI(cash, tau, yea, an);
            console.log(cash);
            break;
        }
    }
    compoundI(cash, tau, yea, an);
})();
```

Comment: Oh ok it was that close. Coming from a little C, JS is so strange for things like this